# PHP echo with Javascript error

Tags: javascript, php

```
'.(($disablez > 0)?'<script type="text/javascript">   $(".lcs_check"").lcs_on(); </script>':"").'
```

Hello, I am using this code inside an echo. but the problem is it doesnt work!. the main point is its a switch that turns ON/OFF and I use PHP codes to get the value but now I want it to be on if it found the disablez more than 0,

I tried putting `$(".lcs_check"").lcs_on();` in a `<style>` outside the echo and it works fine.

Full Echo

```
echo' <form action="" method="post">
<div class="control-group">
<label for="title" class="pull-left label label-info span2">News Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="'.$row["title"].'"" />
                </div>
            </div> <br /><br /><br />
<div>
<label for="content" style="padding-top: 7px;"class="pull-left label label-info span2">Description</label><br /><br />
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"> '.$row["content"].' </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div> <br />
<div class="control-group">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="check-1" id="check-1"value="1" class="lcs_check" autocomplete="off" /></p>
        '.(($disablez > 0)?'<script type="text/javascript">   $(".lcs_check"").lcs_on(); </script>':"").'
                </div>
<div class="control-group">
                <div class="control">
                <input id="addProjectAdd" type="submit" class="btn btn-sharp btn-success" value="Update News" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>';
        }
```

Comment: maybe you copied it wrong? can u provide your full echo sentence?

Comment: Are you sure PHP is actually inserting it into the page? Does your variable contain a number greater than 0? An off-the-wall hunch is that you meant to type "disabled" and not "disablez" there.

Comment: no I've tried everything and I made disablez = 1;

Comment: check browser console for errors  `$(".lcs_check"").lcs_on()` isn't valid syntax

Comment: my browser "chrome"      shows that its like a fake script , the another script in the same page has a colorfull things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '...</p> ' . ($disablez > 0) ? '<script> $(".lcs_check").lcs_on(); </script>':'' . ' </div> ...';
```

If your code is correct, this should do the trick

Update.. Full Code..

```
echo' <form action="" method="post">
<div class="control-group">
<label for="title" class="pull-left label label-info span2">News Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="'.$row["title"].'" />
                </div>
            </div> <br /><br /><br />
<div>
<label for="content" style="padding-top: 7px;"class="pull-left label label-info span2">Description</label><br /><br />
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"> '.$row["content"].' </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div> <br />
<div class="control-group">
        <p><input type="checkbox" name="check-1" id="check-1"value="1" class="lcs_check" autocomplete="off" /></p>
        ' . ($disablez > 0) ? '<script> $(".lcs_check").lcs_on(); </script>':'' . '
                </div>
<div class="control-group">
                <div class="control">
                <input id="addProjectAdd" type="submit" class="btn btn-sharp btn-success" value="Update News" />
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>';
```

Comment: I Guess its the solution , but Its inside an echo so it wont work. can u edit it to work inside the echo? my echo uses '

Comment: I just did. check it again

Comment: You miss understood me , I don't want it inside a new echo, I want it to work inside the current echo. when I pasted ur code it gave me error.

Comment: No man, the three points supposed to mean that the previous code should exist here.

Comment: anw, I just updated it to make it like your full code, check it out

Comment: It's working fine for me..
maybe you have another error?
You used to have two quotes on <input .. value="'.$row["title"].'"" />
make sure to remove the last double quote..

Comment: Can you please provide me the log you're getting?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8uicbm      check this. it looks like a normal text in my browser not a real <script>

Comment: it says also Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: That's a totally different error, make sure that you import the jq and lc-switch libraries at first before echo-ing the script

Comment: Ty bro , I have moved all my <scripts> in the head and I added $(document).ready(function(e) in the echo and it works fine <3

Answer (score 0):

> You had two double quotes in there.

$(".lcs_check").lcs_on();

Comment: Well, that wasn't the problem . it was a mistake from me while copying :( sorry xD.